# Combining 2 IEnumerables of different types with common interface

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created this interface to use as a combined collection for 2 other collections.

Both of my objects(`ourCars` and `ourTrucks`) contain info about my collection of cars and my collection of trucks.

However the fields are not the same, I so I want to create a new collection in which to combine the two.

```
Private Interface carTruckCombo
    Property ID As String  
    Property make As String 
    Property model As String 
End Interface

Dim cars As IEnumerable(Of ourCars) = Enumerable.Empty(Of ourCars)()
Dim trucks As IEnumerable(Of ourTrucks) = Enumerable.Empty(Of ourTrucks)()
```

Now this is where I get stuck...what do I do now?

```
Dim combinedResults As IEnumerable(Of carTruckCombo)
```

Comment: What is the purpose?? I dont think that is possible.

Comment: What fields are not the same?   If the class implement the interface then you can crate an Enumerable of the Interface that has both classes.

Comment: Well I am trying to combine 2 different IEnumerable into one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var combinedResults  = 
    cars.Select(c=>new carTruckCombo{ID=c.ID,make=c.make,model=c.model})
    .Union(tracks.Select(t=>new carTruckCombo{ID=t.ID,make=t.make,model=t.model}));
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you need to make sure that both your `ourCars` and `ourTrucks` types **Implement** the new `carTruckCombo` type. When that is done, you can use code like this:

```
Dim combinedResults = cars.Cast(Of carTruckCombo).Concat(trucks.Cast(Of carTruckCombo))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Concat` method, **HOWEVER (please read before downvote :) )** you are trying to combine 2 seperate types into one collection and unless they both inherit from the same base class then you cannot do Concat.

You might consider creating a base class called `Vehicle` and then derive `ourCars` and `ourTrucks` from this class.

Otherwise you have to transform both of your collections to the same type using a `Select` method.

C#:

```
combinedResults =  cars.Concat(trucks);
```

Comment: i know that most people just look at code and clearly this is NOT the direct answer so most people will just downvote right away.

Comment: yes...this is what I figured...I'd have to use a select method...like select the fields I want, correct?  I tried to start this but failed :(